# How to return `File::open` when compiler says "cannot return value referencing temporary value"?

Tags: rust

How can I return the result of a `File::open` operation in Rust?

The compiler complains that the result is owned by the function, but provides no suggestions, and there's no useful suggestions easily searchable on the web.

**Code:**

```rust
use std::io::{Read, Seek};

trait ReadSeek: Read + Seek {}

fn get_file_reader(path: &'static str) ->
    Result<&mut dyn ReadSeek, Box<dyn Error>> {

    Ok(&mut File::open(path)?)
}
```

**Error:**

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/archive/zipfile.rs:32:9
   |
32 |         Ok(&mut File::open(path)?)
   |         ^^^^^^^^-----------------^
   |         |       |
   |         |       temporary value created here
   |         returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Comment: Yes, thanks @Herohtar. It looks like Google's search results are so bad, now, that you have to add `site:stackoverflow.com` to your query to avoid getting absolute shit results from Stack Overflow copypaste trash sites.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to return a trait object (`dyn ReadSeek`) instead of just returning `File`?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you are returning a reference to data that is owned by your function. The solution is to not return `&` but the `File` itself, in this case a `Box` (owned pointer, unlike `&` which is a reference) because you are using a trait object (dyn).

```rs
fn get_file_reader(path: &'static str) ->
    Result<Box<dyn ReadSeek>, Box<dyn Error>> {

    let file = File::open(path)?;

    Ok(Box::new(file))
}
```

If you don't need the return type to use `dyn` you could do:

```rs
fn get_file_reader(path: &'static str) ->
    Result<File, Box<dyn Error>> {

    let file = File::open(path)?;

    Ok(file)
}
```